# jQuery event.preventDefault() not working in Firefox (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, jsfiddle

This is a kind of similar duplicate to some others here, but I think I'm using `event.preventDefault()` correctly in this case.

Here's a JSFiddle you can see the code with: http://jsfiddle.net/SeEw2/2/

Basically, click the Submit button.

**In Chrome:** Nothing happens - correct response.

**In Firefox**: Page reloads, oh noes!

So why is the page reloading in Firefox and not Chrome? I've been Firebugging it and no errors come up in either...

Comment: The reason this works on Chrome is that Chrome throws a bone to sites that are IE-dependent, by populating `window.event` with the current event before triggering handlers. (And a free reference like your `event` -- because you forgot to include it in your event handler signature, as [ClemDesm was the first to point out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585970/jquery-event-preventdefault-not-working-in-firefox-jsfiddle-included/4586007#4586007) -- means you're falling back on `window.event`.) Firefox throws no such bones to IE-specific code.

Comment: Very informative, thanks T.J. - I never knew that.

Comment: Please post code in the question, not in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The variable `event` in your code is not initialized.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeEw2/4/

extract :

```
 $('#ajaxsearch').click(function(event) {

        // Stop the Search input reloading the page by preventing its default action
        event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you ClemDesm, how silly to miss that. Now it seems to be showing straight up in Firebug's Error Console anyway... hmmm :)

Comment: I wonder why it works in chrome... had the same exact issue and this fixed it.

Comment: @Shikiryu -- You saved me, me too was using function(e) and missing it, Thanks a lot !

Comment: "How is this answer going to help me?" or so I thought. And then I looked at my code .... Btw, the latest version of FF (66.0.2) no longer had the issue and would ignore this just like Chrome, but 60.x.x still did.

Answer (score 9):

Ah I've had a similar problem in that past. Rather than event.preventDefault() try passing the event to:

```
    function ie8SafePreventEvent(e){
    if(e.preventDefault){ e.preventDefault()}
    else{e.stop()};

    e.returnValue = false;
    e.stopPropagation();        
}
```

I know it says IE, but I've never had a problem with it since =]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for a click event on the submit button, why not use the [$(form).submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler?

As long as you have 'return false' at the end of the handler, the page won't reload.

Comment: That's what I'm using now, seems like a better way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I was also using this but with 'submit' and Firefox kept on posting the form. I had to change to 'click' and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because your not passing the event object like `function(event)`, but my question is why even go through all this when you can make the `type="button"` and onclick pass the values?  In essence that what your doing with this whole process.

Comment: Hey, why did I not think of that?! Cheers! I'm now rolling with a `type="button"`. I'm not using `onclick` though, since in the larger scope of things it's more convenient to do it like this.

Comment: I may be wrong (and it doesn't have a relation with the question) but I'm wondering : Does a `type="button"` recognize the _enter_ keyboard touch as a submit? Can't really test it on jsfiddle, can't test it in another way @ my work and I'm curious :)

Comment: When you press Enter with focus on the textbox, it doesn't. But pressing Enter with focus (probably Tabbed) onto the Button itself, yes, it does recognise it as a submit and `preventDefault()` occurs. Is that what you mean? :)

Comment: OK, to clarify - in order to get Enter to work with both text input and on the Submit button, I assigned the id `#ajaxsearch` to the `<form>` tag, then ran `$('#ajaxsearch').submit([...]` - that works with both of them.

Comment: @Jack : Yeah, so it's not really user-friendly IMHO. A _normal_ person won't focus on the button and then press _enter_ to submit a form. Then, I'll be curious to know if a button and a `.submit()` handler would do. It seems like a better solution in this case (no `action` in the `form` (BTW, why do you use a `form` then ;) ?) Anyway with JS disabled, no fallback here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, due my code is a little bit different this may be helpful for other people. My initial code looked like this.

```
<form id="enrollstudentform" onsubmit="return enrollStudents()">
    ...
</form>
```

My js function looked like

```
function enrollStudents() {
    // Stop Form.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Other code
}
```

I had to ***pass the parameter event in the function call and receive it in the function***.

```
<form id="enrollstudentform" onsubmit="return enrollStudents(event)">
    ...
</form>
```

js code:

```
function enrollStudents(event) {
    // Stop Form.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Other code
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This looks like the same answer that Shikiryu gave 5 years earlier ....