# What's wrong with JS (doesn't work in Mozilla)?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a form:

```
<form  name="green" class="form-inline" onchange="javascript:send_choose()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br><br>
  <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" name="linkgreen" id="linkgreen" placeholder="some example"> <br> <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

And JS in the bottom:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> 
function send_choose() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = document.getElementById('linkgreen');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'include/create_file.php',
        data: {
            name4: 'weblink.txt',
            link: link.value
        },
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};
$(document).ready(function () {});
</script>
```

It perfectly works in Chrome and IE and doesn't work in Mozilla.

Comment: This isn't the issue, but get rid of the `javascript:`. It has no usefulness there. Also get rid of `language="JavaScript"`.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in your firefox developer toolbar?

Comment: Your issue is that you have code inside a script that is importing an external file. This is wrong. Use 2 separate `<script>` elements.

Comment: no error messages in debugger of firefox.

Comment: But this code is work proper in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Another issue is that you're trying to use  a global `event` object, which doesn't exist in Firefox. You need to pass it from the handler `onchange="send_choose(event)"` and receive it in the function `function send_choose(event){`

Comment: @inno.vlad When something works properly in one or more browsers does not mean that it is correct. Those browsers might just not care about that invalid syntax.

Comment: @squint is right. Here is a [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585970/jquery-event-preventdefault-not-working-in-firefox-jsfiddle-included) regarding why that is.

Comment: @squint. IT WORKS!! Thank you! Exactly as you said: pass to handler and recive in function (event). Great.

Comment: also, you're using jquery. So why not `$('#linkgreen').val()` instead of `document.getElementById('linkgreen')` and using `.value` on it later? or adding an event listener instead of inline js?

Comment: @KaiQing I'm just starting coding. First steps only. I have to learn a lot.

Comment: no problem. but those little bits of info will spare you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it separates the jquery include `<script>` tag and the `<script` tag for your code, which is the proper way to do things, what you did never works:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function send_choose() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = document.getElementById('linkgreen');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'include/create_file.php',
        data: {
            name4: 'weblink.txt',
            link: link.value
        },
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};
$(document).ready(function () {});
</script>
```

Comment: What did you change? Please hint at the problem that you solved.