# jQuery on click not working FireFox - possibly event.preventdefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, firefox, jquery-events

I have the following which is working on every browser other than Firefox. This appears to be a problem the prevent default action, how can I fix this?

```
$(".subcontent .sidebar .mobileopen").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.subcontent .sidebar .mobileopen').toggleClass('removeborder');
    $('.subcontent .sidebar nav.mobile').slideToggle();
    $('.subcontent .sidebar nav.mobile ul li.menu-item-has-children > a').on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).nextAll('ul').eq(0).slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: $( ".subcontent .sidebar .mobileopen" ).on( "click", function(event) { dont know if this helps. But you need to apply the event on the function

Comment: `event` should be a parameter to the handler function, is what @Tommy correctly suggests :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585970/jquery-event-preventdefault-not-working-in-firefox-jsfiddle-included

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't passed the `event` parameter to the event handler

```
$(".subcontent .sidebar .mobileopen").on("click", function (event) {
                                                            ^^^^^
    event.preventDefault();
```

Mozilla Firefox don't have global `event`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33167145/2025923.

You can also use `return false;` at the end of the event handler to prevent default action of the element from happening. This will also stop event bubbling.

Comment: Thanks - should I put event.preventdefault in there or just event and do that on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
$("body").on("click", ".subcontent .sidebar .mobileopen" function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

});
```